# Keep selection when selected row is clicked with tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Is there an option in tabulator to keep the selection of a row if it is clicked?

For example - assume we have a table of 3 rows. When I click the second row it selected. I would like that click on the second row again will not deselect it (but clicking other rows will deselect it when using `selectable: 1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `row.select()` method on the `rowClick` event to do what you are looking for. This will ensure the row is always selected on click but still deselected when another row is clicked.  Here is an example:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Billy Bob', age: '12', gender: 'male', height: 1, col: 'red', dob: '', cheese: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May', age: '1', gender: 'female', height: 2, col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982', cheese: true },
  { id: 10, name: 'Margret Marmajuke', age: '16', gender: 'female', height: 5, col: 'yellow', dob: '31/01/1999' }
]

const table = new Tabulator('#example-table', {
  data: data,
  selectable: 1,
  columns: [
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age' },
    { title: 'Gender', field: 'gender' },
    { title: 'Height', field: 'height' },
    { title: 'Favourite Color', field: 'col' }
  ]
})

table.on('rowClick', (e, row) => {
  row.select()
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I wonder if there is any option that can be passed that does the same